# The 4.13.x kernels does not boot

Tags: boot, kernel

I have 3 4.13.0 kernels in my Grub menu, -26, -31, -32. None of the boot at all. I am directed back to bios to choose either Windows or the external HDD I have Ubuntu on. However my  4.10.0 -28 works perfect.
I can manage with the old kernel but it is annoying not to be able to use newer kernels. 
/ Gunnar

Ps I bit more info about it. I have been working with Ubuntu the last 15-20 years but never had any problem updating. This time my previous HDD broke so I had to buy a new one. Installing Ubuntu from scratch on a new HDD. It took me some time to get it on the disk. Mostly I ended up with black screen. Finally I got it working on a fresh partition. The working image is the first one in Grub. The first installation from the installation Image.

30/1

### I am not much of OS guy but what I understand from Grub config file the "non working "images are referenced. Here is a piece of it

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-32-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.13.0-32-generic-advanced-caff7239-a5be-41cd-a216-a654f23aab5a' {
    recordfail
savedefault
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  caff7239-a5be-41cd-a216-a654f23aab5a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root caff7239-a5be-41cd-a216-a654f23aab5a
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 4.13.0-32-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic root=UUID=caff7239-a5be-41cd-a216-a654f23aab5a ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.13.0-32-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.13.0-32-generic-init-upstart-caff7239-a5be-41cd-a216-a654f23aab5a' {
    recordfail
```

### etc

My interpretation is that some how the link between the menu entry and the actual booting piece of code is somehow incorrect. 
May be this can help you futher.
/ Gunnar  Please tell me how to proceed to get more trace information

Comment: I think you should report bug to launchpad with `apport-bug linux`. Do your symptoms look like in [this 1745118 bugreport](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1745118), or [bug 1742721](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1742721)?

Comment: Well the  bug 1742721? seems to have been corrected in -21 And I have got 13.0 -26, -31, -32 in my menu.

Comment: The other one 1745118 bugreport seems to loop. Mine does not loop.  Only falls back to bios .

Comment: *"working with Ubuntu the last 15-20 years"* The first Ubuntu was released in 2004.